# Description of Sefirot from Zohar - source please

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, zohar, sefirot-attributes

I heard a Rav say in a shiur that "the Zohar says that 'Hashem brought forth 10 sefirot and personalize/identified with them'".

I would like to know where in the Zohar this is stated, if anyone has any idea?

EDIT: The accepted answer is good enough, but in addition to it, in the comments @shmosel provided a very important source: [בגין דישתמודעון ליה](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%91_%D7%9E%D7%91_%D7%91#:%7E:text=%D7%91%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%94)

Key lines:

> הכי עלת העלות עביד עשר ספירות, וקרא לכתר מקור, וביה לית סוף לנביעו
> דנהוריה, ובגין דא קרא לגרמיה אין סוף, ולית ליה דמות וצורה, ותמן לית
> מאנא למתפס ליה למנדע ביה ידיעא כלל, ובגין דא אמרו ביה, במופלא ממך אל
> תדרוש, ובמכוסה ממך אל תחקור.
>
> לבתר עבד מאנא זעירא ודא י', ואתמליא מניה, וקרא ליה מעין נובע חכמה,
> **וקרא גרמיה בה חכם**, ולההוא מאנא קרא ליה חכמ"ה, ולבתר עבד מאנא רברבא,
> וקרא ליה ים, וקרא ליה בינה, והוא קרא לגרמיה מבין בה.

Which can't be more direct: Hashem brought forth these sefirot and identified with them.

Comment: [פתח אליהו](https://www.tfilah.org/brachot/%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97-%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95/)

Comment: @shmosel thank you, but I can't see where it says that Hashem identifies/personalizes with them? It says He reveals Himself through them and conceals Himself through them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tikkunei Zohar 17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Tikkunei_Zohar.17a.2?vhe=Hebrew_Wikipedia&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) which says:

> The prophet Elijah, of blessed memory, opened, and said: Eternal Hidden Master of the worlds! You are He whose Unity is infinite and absolute, and therefore indivisible. You are He1, transcendent beyond all that is above, and concealed behind all that is concealed. No thought whatsoever can grasp You. ***But You are He who brought forth ten rectifications - we call them the ten sefirot*** Atzilut - with which to regulate hidden worlds that are not revealed, as well as worlds that are revealed. Indeed, it is through these that You are hidden from human beings. You are He who binds them and unifies them. And inasmuch as You are within them, anyone who separates one from the other is regarded as having caused a separation in You.

This text is recited by many at Mincha of erev Shabbat.

If you continue to read the text cited above it explains how the Sefirot correspond to G-d's name.

> ואלו עשר הספירות, משתלשלות כסדרן: אחת ארוכה, ואחת קצרה, ואחת בינונית. ואתה הוא שמנהיג אותם, ואין מי שינהיג אותך, לא למעלה, לא למטה ולא משום צד. לבושים הכנת להם, מהם פורחות נשמות לבני אדם, וכמה גופים הכנת להם שנקראים גוף לגבי הלבושים המכסים עליהם, ונקראים בתיקונם כך: חסד - זרוע ימין, גבורה - זרוע שמאל, תפארת - הגוף. נצח והוד - שתי שוקיים. יסוד - סיום הגוף, אות ברית קודש. מלכות - פה, תורה שבעל פה היא נקראת.
>
> חכמה - המוח, והוא פנימיות המחשבה. בינה - היא הלב, ובה הלב מבין. ועל שני אלו כתוב "הַנִּסְתָּרתֹ לַה' אלהֵינוּ". כתר עליון הוא, והוא כתר מלכות, ועליו נאמר - "מגִּיד מֵרֵאשִּית אַחֲרִּית", והיינו תפילין של ראש. בפנימיות הוא יו"ד ה"א וא"ו ה"א, והוא בדרך אצילות, המשקה את האילן בזרועותיו וענפיו, כמים המשקים לאילן ומתגדלים אותו בהשקיה זו.

That in this text, the Sefirot are equated with the letters of G-d's name (יהוה). They are imagined in vertical orientation, from top to bottom beginning with the letter Yud.

In orientation like this, they form the shape which corresponds with and is the paradigm for a male physical body. It also corresponds to the form of the Mishkan and Mikdash when viewing it from above. For details, see diagrams relating to Hilchot Beit HaBechirah in the Mishneh Torah.

The letter Yud corresponding with the head which contains the brain of Chochmah. The Kutz or Crown at the top of Yud is Keter.

The Nexus point between the bottom of the Yud, the cross beam of the first Heh and the top of the Vav is the place of the heart which corresponds to Binah. This is why Binah is described with the qualities of breadth and depth.

The right and left arms of the first letter Heh correspond with Chesed and Gevurah.

The main body of the letter Vav corresponds with Tiferet.

The nexus point between the end of the Vav and the cross beam of the second Heh is called *the end of the body*. This corresponds with Yesod while the right and left legs of the second Heh correspond to Netzach and Hod.

What is called the *Mouth* is referring to what would correspond to the mouth of the genitals. That corresponds to Malchut.

There is a similar, but different scheme for G-d's name which corresponds to the human female. But that is not outlined in this section of the Zohar.

Comment: Thank you Yaacov. The most interesting part of the question for me is where he said that He identifies/personalizes with them. Can you see that in this text or any other?

Comment: Yes, that follows from the idea that the Sefirot are also related to the letters of G-d's name.

Comment: Interesting, would you be able to edit your answer, include the quote, and explain how that follows briefly and I can accept it as answer. Especially how that reconciles with the passage in the above that Hashem is beyond all names

Comment: [בגין דישתמודעון ליה](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%91_%D7%9E%D7%91_%D7%91#:~:text=%D7%91%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%94)

Comment: @shmosel As in Adam knew Chava, his wife...

Comment: @YaacovDeane I am perplexed. It sounds like you are taking "personalize" a bit more literally than I do. When I say personalize (based, again on the shiur I am referencing) it means that He puts Himself into it completely. Identifies with it. "You want to know Me? I get angry (gevura) when you sin, I love it (chesed) when you are kind to each other - that's Me, Who I am, what I am all about". I felt you were getting there with the name business, and maybe you did, but I think I would like you to explain a bit further if possible? Sorry for all the bother, either way I appreciate your efforts!

Comment: @shmosel could you read what I wrote above to Yaacov, as I think the Raya Mehemna you just brought is also not quite the topic I am referring to i.e. it says there אבל בתר דעבד האי דיוקנא דמרכבה דאדם עלאה, which is what I think you are showing me as the answer to my question but I don't mean His Chariot, I mean what I said to Yaacov, thank you.

Comment: The problem is not with the explanation. It's with how you are understanding the Shiur you are citing. G-d doesn't change like it is stated explicitly in Malachi 3:6 which says: כִּ֛י אֲנִ֥י יְהוָ֖ה לֹ֣א שָׁנִ֑יתִי וְאַתֶּ֥ם בְּנֵֽי־יַעֲקֹ֖ב לֹ֥א כְלִיתֶֽם׃
Our relationship and connection with G-d is via His name only. It is the 'handle', so to speak, to which we can grasp anything. That's why we answer, "Blessed is He and blessed is His name."

Comment: @YaacovDeane I don't disagree with the fact that He doesn't change, of course, so perhaps the problem is none of the above, but simply we are not understanding each other, or we understand those words differently. Thanks for trying. I'll try to ponder on your words more. This getting out of scope for a comments section either way.

Comment: @shmosel nevermind, I just finished reading your source, and I think I got it: וקרא ליה מעין נובע חכמה, וקרא גרמיה בה חכם. This is exactly what I am looking for, thanks!

Comment: FYI, ברוך הוא meaning לעצמותו (drawing down a revelation of His essence via His structure, the root of His name). וברוך שמו to the revelation of G-d below via His name and it's expansion from that initial connection downward. That ברוך with the letters is 232, ע׳ב, ס׳ג, מ׳ה, ב׳ן.

Comment: @RabbiKaii "When I say personalize (based, again on the shiur I am referencing) it means that He puts Himself into it completely." This also follows the text further on. What you are thinking of is referred to as מהות (being), in contrast to עצמות (structure: think like skeleton which is not seen externally & whose inner core, marrow, is the source of the blood in which the animating should is dressed.). This follows the Gra and is also seen in the teachings of the Tzemach Tzedek in Sefer HaLikuttim.

Comment: @YaacovDeane if you would like to discuss this further, happy to open a chat. I don't want the moderators to remove this altogether to chat as it contains useful (imho) information for all. Happy to chat further about it, you are very wise on topics of great interest to me. If you do so, please @ mention me there. Thanks again for all.

Comment: Just tagging this very fundamental source the #PatachEliyahu. Edot Mizrach recite it every day before Shacharit btw

Comment: @NissimNanach On this subject, have you ever reflected on, "מלכות - פה, תורה שבעל פה היא נקראת."? It relates to the Dalet of the word Echod in Shema, the 4 directions of the world & Bereshit 2:8-10. (ויטע גן-בעדן). Four times עדן is מלכות (the 4 streams that split from 1 stream). The phrase עדן מקדם. That קדם refers to the Miluy of Shem "Tov". Eden from Kedem (144-124) is 20. Thus 4 times 20 is "Peh", meaning Torah She'Baal Peh as Eliyahu teaches. The גן refers to the 53 parshiyot of the Written Torah. Thus, Bereshit 2:8-10 is saying that G-d implanted the Written Torah with the Oral Torah.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I hadn't khapped that, is that from the Kisse Melekh or you discerned it? 
And re the mouth I think it's mouth mamash but it and the lower orifice are one insofar as like R' Nachman mentions the upper and lower mouths have similar anatomy, and Tikkun haBrit and Shmirat Habrit are interdependent  תִּקּוּן הַבְּרִית וּשְׁלֵמוּת לְשׁוֹן הַקֹּדֶשׁ הֵם תְּלוּיִים זֶה בָּזֶה L. Moharan #19

Comment: @NissimNanach If by Kisse Melech, you refer to the commentary of Buzaglo, the answer is no. It’s simply the product of hitbodedut. Regarding what Eliyahu is referring to, he states explicitly he is talking about Malchut in this context. I only pointed out where he draws his message from. It’s Bereshit 2:8-10. The 4 “streams from a single stream” are the 4 dimensions which comprise the Oral Torah (Pardes). In context as “mouth” (פה) the Sod level has 2 dimensions, Raz and Raz d’Razin (Kabbalah & Chassidut). The concept of “mouth” related to the 2 levels of Brit is directly from Sefer Yetzirah.